# how to place formatted code in a placeholder in an html

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder, pre

I would like to have a formatted piece of code/json in my html placeholder.
I would like the placeholder to be formatted the way I have it in the html.

i.e.

```html
   <textarea rows="9" data-bind="textInput: someVariable" 
     class="form-control" 
     placeholder=
        'e.g.
        {
            "type": "service_type",
            "project_id": "test-237012",        
            "client_email": "test@test-237012.gserviceaccount.com",
            "client_id": "111390682349634407434",
            ....
        }'>   
    </textarea>
```

How ?

Comment: I checked your code. It works for me in firefox. What is wrong with your placehoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to add the `cols` attribute as well. See below.

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" placeholder='e.g.
    {
        "type": "service_type",
        "project_id": "test-237012",        
        "client_email": "test@test-237012.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": "111390682349634407434",
        ....
    }'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The important part is not to have any whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks) between the opening and the closing tag. Any whitespace would prevent the placeholder from showing up.

```
<textarea
  attribute1="value1"
  attribute2="value2"
  ...
></textarea>
```

When the placeholder text gets cut off, you can either use `cols` and `rows` attributes or define a CSS style with `height` and `width` attributes for the text area.